# How to create a list string display

Tags: flutter, dart

My string is corrected like so:

```
String mathStatements;
```

This list stores data for comments made by app users. I would like to display the most recently created comment in a text box on my app and have been doing it like so:

```
Container(
    child: class.mathStatements == null
     new Text(class.mathStatements),
```

which works fine. However, I am trying to repeat the process with a list string:

```
List<String> askedQuestions
```

but it no longer works and gives me the error message "The argument type 'List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'".
How can I resolve this?

Comment: `Text(askedQuestions.toString()),` use like this .tostring() method use to convert any object to string

Answer (score 0):

[Recommended] If you want to show it as a list view, use `ListView`.

```dart
ListView(
  children: askedQuestions.map((e) {
    return Text(e);
  }).toList(),
)
```

Or, If you want to show it using one text widget see the below code.

```dart
Text(askedQuestions.reduce((value, element) => value + '\n' + element));
```